# Under which circumstances does the System process (PID 4) retain an open file handle?

Tags: winapi, file, locking, handle

My application running on a Windows server makes use of a Jet/Access database. For some reasons around every two weeks that database file gets locked by the System process (PID 4, seems to be fixed)

After some googling I found some other users having their files locked by that special process, but different files (of course).

- What's the general reason for the System process to keep an open file handle?
- Is my application the cause for this locking situation?
- Are all handles implicitly opened by the System process? I could imagine that after a process has crashed, the handle may still be open and the System process somehow takes owernship of that handle.
- Can I do something in my application to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds to me like a driver-level issue with a leaky handle.

If you're running an anti-virus package try upgrading, disabling (temporarily!) or switching to a different brand.

Answer (score 47):

Files accessed through a share will be locked by the system process (PID 4).

Try opening `compmgmt.msc` -> *System Tools* -> *Shared Folders* -> *Open Files* to see if the locked file is listed there

See also [the sysinternals forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/handleexe-error-closing-handle-invalid-handle_topic25377.html) for a way to replicate this.
Not all applications lock files when they are opened, Excel however does.  I don't know if Access does the same...

Comment: This one was my issue exactly. A user was running an executable via unc path to a remote machine and even after the app closed itself down, the handle remained open on the remote machine. Super easy to troubleshoot with psfile and handle.exe from sysinternals.

Comment: You are the best, I've tried many other solutions with no success. Thanks

Comment: This worked. Using sysinternal's `handle` or `procexp` couldn't close the file, although they did tell me what the problem was so that I was able to find this answer. My issue happened when I was running `docker` on Windows via Hyper-V. A server running within docker had created a file which was subsequently locked by the `system` process. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh man, big thanks for this one. It looks quite simple and easy until it happens in HA production environment locking things down. Do I need a "File Removal Specialist" badge now?

Answer (score 29):

Here's another possible cause I've found:

There is a bug in Windows 7 and likely in Windows Server 2008 (possibly 64bit versions only). It surfaces when you disable [Application Experience](http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/application-experience/) service and causes the same problems as described in the question.

Re-enabling this service has fixed this problem for me.

A bit more info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/fcdde3bc-43a1-4ab6-b0b5-9525fe4e84c8) as to why it's causing a problem.

List of other SO questions which seem to be related:

- [Visual Studio output file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312646/visual-studio-output-file-permissions)
- [Windows 2008 R2 - Kernel (System Process PID=4) is locking files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378192/windows-2008-r2-kernel-system-process-pid-4-is-locking-files-and-folders)

Comment: +1 this worked for me and I'm not running any anti-virus, so it is really something odd going on.

Comment: My God, how the hell does one find out that Application Experience is responsible for this? Must have been one lucky fella. Thanks so much for this, I can finally work on this PC again!

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Not sure about OP, but I personally found out the hard way: After a long tweaking session where I disabled a ton of Windows services, Steam (gaming application) became unable to update. It complained about a file being in use. If I remember correctly, Process Explorer showed the file in question being used by either explorer.exe or System, which I found odd. I eventually reset the service configurations and the problem disappeared. From there on, I disabled them once again, one by one, until the offender was found :/.

Comment: I've placed a note to self never to disable this service again. Better yet, I probably should't touch any Microsoft / Windows services for that matter! I'm so glad I stumbled upon your answer, so many other alternate solutions led to nothing or some other scenarios were just a little off in which specific error / process / service was hogging the file.

Answer (score 7):

It may be a lingering session from a remote computer to a shared folder. If that's the case, it can be unlocked from the command line:

```
net session /delete
```

Comment: I was a bit worried about running this command because I was afraid of side effects.  I ran `net session` first and it reported one connection.  I then ran the command and it prompted for each session it killed.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was "Windows Defender" (anti-virus). I excluded my Visual Studio build folders from Windows Defender's list of folders it checks, and the problem went away. (Visual Studio wasn't able to build to the EXE file, PID 4 was locking it to check for virii)

Answer (score 1):

Is your server set up to perform periodic file backups?

If so, is the backup running as System, perhaps prompting the locked file when you get a conflict?

Comment: How can any process be running as the System process? Just to be sure, I'm not talking about the SYSTEM user, but the process called System with PID=4.

Comment: That rule wasn't well established when this post was made. If you'd edited instead, you could have scored an Excavator badge. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to hit it with a sledgehammer. Chkdsk /f on the drive where the folder was located fixed it. Use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the security settings for each folder and subfolders. Make sure that the system did not just automatically create a special permissions setting which will not allow anyone to delete the file. Apparently for some odd reason the OS creates a weird special permission setting that protects the file from being deleted.