# MinGW created file with weird permissions?

Tags: c, windows-7, mingw

When I compile a C-Program with MinGW and I want to remove the exe-file it disappears. But when I hit F5 it is still there. Unlocker can't find any handles and also can't remove it. I can't modify the permissions and can't change the owner. After about 2 minutes the file gets removed. It also appears before the file was executed.

My System: Windows 7 Professional x86. My link line from makefile:

```
gcc -o main.exe main.o -lopengl32 -lglut32 -lglu32
```

How to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean it disappears after two minutes? Are you sure that the process isn't running in the background? is your program doing some complex mathematics in a different thread that it is stopping to execute? Please share more information. The question has insufficient information for an answer.

Comment: no, it also happens before executing.

Comment: I suspect virus scanner keeping the file open.

Comment: no, it also happens without the scanner :(

Comment: Must be related to your code. Too bad we can not see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I still don't know why the permissions are modified, but I found out it also happens with other (e.g. downloaded) .exe files. Solution: Reinstall Windows.

EDIT: Don't know why, but I just had to reenable the Application Expirence Service and it worked. Don't know why....

Comment: The permissions aren't modified. Some software has the file open, probably a virus scanner, but possibly something else, like google desktop search. You may have more than one virus scanner installed, often Windows Defender is installed as well as a regular virus scanner.

Answer (score 1):

A file can be deleted while open, but will not actually be removed from the filesystem until the last handle is closed.

I suspect in your case it is a virus scanner keeping the file open.

EDIT See also:

- [Visual Studio output file permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312646/visual-studio-output-file-permissions)

Apparrently this is a known issue when disabling the "Application Experience Service".

Comment: Sorry, Unlocker can't find any handles.

Comment: @das_j, so what? Who says Unlocker knows everything? Try turning off your AV and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: i think the permissions are modified. in a weird way

Comment: @das_j, these sorts of problems are almost always caused by virus scanners. Check you don't have two virus scanners - Windows Defender might be installed as well as your other one.