# Process Explorer: How to find out what System PID 4 is

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, process-explorer

Using Process Explorer I can see that a certain file is locked by "System, PID: 4".
This blocks the VB.NET VS2012 IDE from recreating the file.
I am getting the "Permission denied" error.

I have tried to disable just anything that might lock my file... Application compatibility, Backups, Windows Defender, Windows Indexer, just anything I could think of.

How could I find out which application "System, PID: 4" really is?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this may be better off being moved over to SuperUser as it's a system question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Adrian I am not sure although open for criticism. I have seen this "error" a few times already related to VB.NET, but I think nobody else dug this much down to the problem.

Comment: My point is that what you're asking is related to the operating system and the use of ProcessExplorer, not a question of programming as far as I can tell.  StackExchange has other sites for asking questions of that nature.

Comment: @Adrian Do you think that anybody interested in this topic would use SuperUser? I am just asking because I have never used it.

Comment: To quote SuperUser's own description: "Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users."  Apart from the fact that "System" is the name of the process running in PID 4, you're more likely to find people who can help you dig further -- if possible -- there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Windows 2008 R2 - Kernel (System Process PID=4) is locking files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378192/windows-2008-r2-kernel-system-process-pid-4-is-locking-files-and-folders)

It is a Microsoft bug.

Enabling the Application Experience solved my problem.
Not sure which program disabled it.

I just typed services.msc in the Windows start menu.
Then I located the service "Application experience" and restarted it.